# Document and image thumbnails via GoogleApps Script not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I used to get the Google generated thumbnail for Google Docs files and image files when executing the code below but now I only get null values. I have even tried sharing the files as public on the web.

```
function testThumbnail(){
    var theFile = DriveApp.getFileById('PlaceTestFileIDHere');//Use a test file id here
    //Show that you have a valid file by logging the name
    Logger.log(theFile.getName());
    //Get the Thumbnail
    var aBlob = theFile.getThumbnail();
   //Test the thumbnail result
   if(aBlob == null){
       Logger.log('no Thumbnail');
   }
   else{
       Logger.log(theFile.getThumbnail().getBytes());
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that you have a file that goes by: 'PlaceTestFileIDHere' in your drive?

Comment: 'PlaceTestFileIDHere' is just place holder for and actual FileID of a file on Google drive.  I did this so that anyone would be able to perform a quick test using the above sample code just replacing the text with their own fileId to see that they get the same behaviour or what to adjust to get a thumbnail.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getThumbnailLink(fileId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  return file.thumbnailLink;
}

var selectedDocument  =  app.createImage(getThumbnailLink(theFile.getId()))
```

Rather use the Drive service as shown above it works very well.